# Pros and Cons usage await in the map with promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, async-await

I'm wondering about: is there any negative effect for using await in the loops like map / for...of ?

And what is the cons & pros about that ?

```js
await Promise.all(products.map(async (product) => {
      await Product.CreateProductIfDoesntExists(params);
}));
```

Comment: In case you assume differently, all promises start essentially at the same time; they don't run consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

You asked about await in loops but your example shows a specific kind of loop, calling `map` so, await in map

Pro:

- Lots of requestw get started, possibly all in parallel so likely much faster depending on what `Product.CreateProductIfDoesntExists` does

Con:

- Potentially uses too much memory depending on how many products there are and what kind of work `Product.CreateProductIfDoesntExists` does

Here's a simple example: In this case 5 things means 80 meg is used at once but it finishes in 2 seconds

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function processThing() {
  const data = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024 * 16);
  await wait(2000);
  return data[data.length - 1];  // pretend we use data
}

async function main() {
  const things = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
  
  await Promise.all(things.map(async(thing) => {
        await processThing(thing);
  }));
  console.log('--done--');
}
main();
```

vs this one, only 16 meg is ever used, but it takes 10 seconds

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function processThing() {
  const data = new Uint8Array(1024 * 1024 * 16);
  await wait(2000);
  return data[data.length - 1];  // pretend we use data
}

async function main() {
  const things = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
  
  for (const thing of things) {
     await processThing(thing);
  }
  console.log('--done--');
}
main();
```

If the first example using `map` used more memory per thing or had to process 1000 things or 10000s things you could easily run out of memory.

The second example won't run out of memory as it's only processing one thing at a time.

There is nothing wrong with using await in map, unless you know ahead of time that the stuff that's going to happen inside takes tons of memory or the number of items processed will be very large.

The second example is probably less than ideal. If you really wanted to handle 1000 or 10000 things you'd still probably want to process them several at a time (say 10 at a time) and so you'd need a far more complex queue of work to make that efficient.

Comment: I might be missing something, but afaik, the things you describe occur whether there's an `await` in the callback or not. You're essentially listing pros and cons of `Promise.all`

Comment: It's got nothing to do with Promise.all, it has to do with using await inside `map`

Comment: I forgot to add promise.all to the subject :). thanks for your comments.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer. Whether or not you wait for all things to complete with `Promise.all` they are still all potentially doing things at the same time. Downloading data, decoding images. Whether it's an issue depends on what's actually happening in your Product.CreateProductIfDoesntExists. All Promise.all does is wait for all the promises. It doesn't change how they execute.

Comment: So it should be without Promise.all to execute one by one like below am I right ? 
```javascript
products.map(async (product) => {
      await Product.CreateProductIfDoesntExists(params);
});
```

Comment: Like it says in my preivous comment. Promise.all is irrielvant to the con I mentioned in my answer. As for whether you should use Promise.all or map or neither or both it depends on your needs. There is no correct answer. There's just what's approproiate for your situation.